# Error when updating record com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: user-interface, user-input

I am trying to create a phonebook system, where users have an application and they can add, delete, edit and search. I keep getting this error in the edit contact:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in '%john%' or lastname in '%john%'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1618)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
at PhoneBook.main(PhoneBook.java:112)
```

This is the code used for the edit contact:

```
}else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
                            System.out.println("Type in the name you would like to edit :\n");
                            String data=s.next().trim();


                            stmt = con.createStatement();
                            String sql = "UPDATE contacts" + "WHERE firstname in '%"+data+"%' or lastname in '%"+data+"%'";

                            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


                            sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email, number FROM contacts";
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);


                            while(rs.next()){
                               //Retrieve column 
                               String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
                               String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
                               String email = rs.getString("email");
                               String number = rs.getString("number");

                               //Display
                               System.out.println("First Name: " + firstname + "\n");
                               System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastname + "\n");
                               System.out.println("Email: " + email + "\n");
                               System.out.println("Number: " + number + "\n");
                            }
                            rs.close();
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in where clause , update query first find the record which you want to edit then it set new value.

Answer (score 0):

String sql = "UPDATE contacts" + "WHERE firstname in '%"+data+"%' or lastname in '%"+data+"%'";

update contacts set firstname="abc",lastname="bcd"  WHERE firstname in '%"+data+"%' or lastname in '%"+data+"%'";

Comment: but I want the user to first enter the name they would like to edit then edit the contact. How can I do that please? Since you set firstname to "abc" and lastname to "bcd"?